# Not Able to work with PostgreSQL though all settings in php.ini is enable

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I am working with PHP and using a Postgres database. But I am not able to connect the application with the Postgres database, I get an error:

```
Call to undefined function pg_connect()
```

I have referred to lots of link to try and solve this. I have a solution, which is to enable `php_pgsql` and also enable `php_pdo_pgsql`. I have done this but it has still not been able to connect. I am still getting the same error. I have reinstalled WAMP but that also does not resolve the error.

Comment: does php_info(); list postgres module?..

Comment: Did you restart Apache after enabling the module? If you reinstall, it may set the module off again.

Comment: Yes mark I always restart wamp server after reenable module. And When I use php_info(); I see that postgree is not in list. I have did all the module enable which are connecting with postgree but not able to find proper solution. When I start my WAMP server I get error like "Unable to load dynamic library 'D:/.../php_pdo_pgsql.dll' The specified module cound not be found.

Comment: @Marc That was an issue with installation because. I have reInstall WAMP and make all settings require, It is working fine.